# Count a certain column if a separate date column is from the previous month

Tags: excel, countif

In excel, there's a column on my "data" tab (column E) that I need to count if is greater than 0. I need to only count those if the lock date (column F) was in the previous month. I thought I had it figured out but it keeps returning 0. This is what I have that is not returning anything:

```
=COUNTIFS(Data!E:E,">0"+">="&EOMONTH(TODAY(),-2)+1,Data!F:F,"<"&EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)+1)
```

[image]

Comment: Please go back through your history and mark answers that you used as correct by clicking the check mark by that answer.  You are the only one that can do that.  It till remove the question from the unanswered queue and reward the answerer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually put the column f in twice:

```
=COUNTIFS(Data!E:E,">0",Data!F:F,">="&EOMONTH(TODAY(),-2)+1,Data!F:F,"<"&EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to add a column that determines whether the row is included in the count. Something like: `=AND(E2>0,MONTH(F2)=MONTH(TODAY())-1)`.

Then, you just need to run the `COUNTIF` function against that new column.